# Debian USB Error

Tags: linux, debian, wifi, usb

I am using Debina LXDE(Jessie) on Lichee Pi Zero Eval. Board. This board hasn't got a wifi hardware. So, i am using a wireless usb adapter for wifi connection.(Adapter: <Link: [https://www.amazon.com/USB-N10-NANO-Network-Adapter-USB/dp/B00GCB2XII/ref=sr_1_2?crid=3OS31YIMGOX64&keywords=Asus+Usb-N10&qid=1673332275&sprefix=asus+usb-n10%2Caps%2C166&sr=8-2>](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00GCB2XII)).

I used this device for a while and it was working properly.But then it started giving the following error:

[image]

I thought the usb port of the card I was using was broken, but the wireless mouse and wired mouse are working properly.

[image]

I thought the USB Wifi Adapter was broken, but it was working when I tested it on my laptop.

When I searched the internet for the given error(error -110), I saw that it might be caused by low voltage. But this system worked for a while as it was. I still fed it with a different voltage source but I got this error again.

Normally I was supplying voltage with USB Hub <[Link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07G8CMR18)>
But since this didn't work, I used a power supply.<[Link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00O8DJ8QC)>

How can I fix this problem and get this wifi adapter working?

Comment: I'm curious what `This board support wifi but hasn't got a wifi hardware` even means. *How can I fix this problem and get this wifi adapter working?* I would invest in a decent power supply - you haven't mentioned the ratings of the ones you've used, so I'm guessing they are probably cheap garbage :p

Comment: Yes, it was a silly sentence, I made some corrections. But the power supplies I use are sufficient for this job. @JaromandaX

Comment: Such issues are mostly due to improper power management by underlying device. Newer kernel might have resolved this issue. Try plugging in this adapter into USB 2.0 port

Comment: Sory but there is only one usb port available. [link](https://imgaz.staticbg.com/thumb/large/oaupload/banggood/images/9B/C5/621a27cc-bc36-4c92-9c07-9aae42545a3e.jpeg) @SHW

Comment: if there is a problem with the power, how could it have worked before? @SHW

Comment: @SpeedyGonzales When system goes in sleep/hibernation, it performs power management tasks. But few devices fails to reply such power management. I had faced this issue and to avoid the issue, I do have to rmmod before sleep/hibernation and modprobe after wakeup. OP might have different issue, but thought it's a worth to give a shot

Comment: In my case, said WiFi device works only when I keep the system down for least 5 min. OR I have to perform rmmod/modprobe as stated above

Comment: I don't know about rmmod/modprobe. How can I do that? @SHW

Comment: How should I schedule "before sleep/hibernation" and "after wakeup"? @SHW

Comment: @SpeedyGonzales https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-suspend.service.html
You might have to write `systemd-wakeup.service`. Since I am old school, I prefer custom scripts for everything

Comment: Do I have to create the systemd-wakeup.service file myself? @SHW

Comment: Yes. That's what I mentioned in earlier comment.

Comment: Please, [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086)